# Shortest common superstring in java

Tags: java

I have a program from internet

[Shortest Common Super String](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/shortest-superstring-problem/)

The program gives proper output however when I converted the program in java it's not giving the same output. I have the pasted my java program below

```
public class ShortestCommonSuperString {

    private static int min(int a, int b) {
        return (a < b) ? a : b;
    }

    // Function to calculate maximum overlap in two given strings
    private static int findOverlappingPair(String str1, String str2, RefObjectOne<String> str) {
        int max = -2147483648;
        int len1 = str1.length();
        int len2 = str2.length();

        for (int i = 1; i <= min(len1, len2); i++) {
            // compare last i characters in str1 with first i
            // characters in str2
            if (str1.regionMatches(0, str2, str2.length() - i - 1, i) == false) {
                if (max < i) {
                    max = i;
                    str.argValue = str1 + str2.substring(i);
                }
            }
        }

        // check prefix of str1 matches with suffix of str2
        for (int i = 1; i <= min(len1, len2); i++) {
            // compare first i characters in str1 with last i
            // characters in str2
            if (str1.regionMatches(str1.length() - i - 1, str2, 0, i) == false) {
                if (max < i) {
                    //update max and str
                    max = i;
                    str.argValue = str2 + str1.substring(i);
                }
            }
        }

        return max;
    }

    private static String findShortestSuperstring(String[] arr, int len) {
        // run len-1 times to consider every pair
        while (len != 1) {
            System.out.println("Wokring While");
            int max = -2147483648; // to store maximum overlap
            int l = 0; // to store array index of strings
            int r = 0;
            // involved in maximum overlap
            String resStr = null; // to store resultant string after
            String str = null;
            // maximum overlap

            for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                System.out.println("Working For ONE");
                for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                    System.out.println("Working For TWO");
                    RefObjectOne<String> tempRef_str = new RefObjectOne<String>(str);
                    int res = findOverlappingPair(arr[i], arr[j], tempRef_str);
                    str = tempRef_str.argValue;
                    System.out.println(str);
                    // check for maximum overlap
                    if (max < res) {
                        max = res;
                        resStr = str;
                        l = i;
                        r = j;
                    }
                }
            }

            len--; //ignore last element in next cycle

            // if no overlap, append arr[len] to arr[0]
            if (max == -2147483648) {
                arr[0] += arr[len];
            } else {
                arr[l] = resStr; // copy resultant string to index l
                arr[r] = arr[len]; // copy string at last index to index r
            }
        }
        return arr[0];
    }

    // Driver program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] arr = {"catgc", "ctaagt", "gcta", "ttca", "atgcatc"};
        int len = arr.length;
        System.out.println("The shortest super string is" + findShortestSuperstring(arr, len));
    }
}

class RefObjectOne<T> {
    public T argValue;

    public RefObjectOne(T refArg) {
        this.argValue = refArg;
    }
}
```

The output I am getting is like this -> The shortest superstring catgctc 
Which is not the right output. Not able to figure out where I am doing mistake

Comment: A Debugger can help you

Comment: You'll probably be faster to write your own (readable) implementation based on the pseudocode in that link.  That way you'll probably understand the code, and you'll probably end up with something more maintainable.

Comment: Here is a java program which works. https://github.com/superzhu/Algorithms/blob/master/String/src/main/java/string/ShortestCommonSuperstring.java

Answer (score 0):

You have to use proper arguments for regionMatches(). This is correct:

```
// Function to calculate maximum overlap in two given strings
private static int findOverlappingPair(String str1, String str2, RefObjectOne<String> str) {
    int max = -2147483648;
    int len1 = str1.length();
    int len2 = str2.length();

    for (int i = 1; i <= min(len1, len2); i++) {
        // compare last i characters in str1 with first i
        // characters in str2
        if (str1.regionMatches(len1 - i, str2, 0, i)) {
            if (max < i) {
                max = i;
                str.argValue = str1 + str2.substring(i);
            }
        }
    }

    // check prefix of str1 matches with suffix of str2
    for (int i = 1; i <= min(len1, len2); i++) {
        // compare first i characters in str1 with last i
        // characters in str2
        if (str1.regionMatches(0, str2, len2 - i, i)) {
            if (max < i) {
                // update max and str
                max = i;
                str.argValue = str2 + str1.substring(i);
            }
        }
    }

    return max;
}
```